# How can I reformat microSD cards that were created read-only?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, format, fat32, micro-sd-card

My company was burning some microSD cards (4000 of them) and the multi burning machine we were using gives us the option to make the microSD read-only.

I didn't know this was possible, but apparently it flips a binary switch in the microSD card.

We now need to reformat all 4000 of the microSD cards and start fresh. We cannot format them because they are read only. I am not using a SD adapter so the possibility of the lock switch is a non issue.

Gparted cannot format them and running this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw  /media/48EC-B32A
```

… returns this error:

> cannot remount block device /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected

Is there any way to force format these or are they permamantly gone?

Comment: +1 good question. Unfortulatelly, I think the only way is using the hardware lock.

Comment: Are you able to remove the partition completely and recreate it? It may be that the partition is RO but you should be able to remove it still, instead of reformating.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/106841/mount-locked-sd-card-as-read-write-in-gnu-linux

Comment: Recall what brand your multi-burning machine was?

Comment: Tell us more about this "burning" machine.

Comment: are you able to `fdisk /dev/sdb1` and use the `o (create a new empty dos partition table)` action? issue `w` after to update the device filesystem. If not... sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 1):

The SD card should be unmounted before attempting format.

You will probably need to use mkdosfs

for FAT16

```
mkdosfs /dev/sdb2 -F16
```

or for FAT32

```
mkdosfs /dev/sdb2 -F32
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found [more information on this](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked):

SD cards have a physical lock, to write protect the card. MicroSD cards don't have the lock, but the SD *adapter* has it, and it can lock-unlock the card.

So, try to put the card in an adapter and slid the lock a few times, leaving it on unlocked.

Answer (score -4):

Sorry, for previous answer, I mixed up!

Can you use the something like HirenBoot CD?

Maybe that helps.

Comment: Original poster specifically mentions that `mount -o remount,rw` fails, you're suggesting essentially the same thing.